# How many columns we can create in a table in SQLite?

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I am creating a SQLite database for my iPhone projects. I have table called products in my database.

I want to have 35 columns in the products table. I am able to create 26 columns only. I add any more its not getting added to the table. I am accessing the database via SQLite manager from Firefox. Is there any limit for the columns. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: The default limit is 2000 (see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)). If you are adding them by hand through a UI, I can only guess that the UI is broken. What are the column names, btw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely a limitation of the Firefox plugin or has to do with your naming setup. From the SQLite [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html):

> The default setting for SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN is 2000. You can change it
>   at compile time to values as large as 32767. On the other hand, many
>   experienced database designers will argue that a well-normalized
>   database will never need more than 100 columns in a table.

Solution: use the command line interface sqlite3.

Comment: There was some mistake in firefox. when i tried it on other system it was working fine.